# How can I control manual flash settings on top of the camera using Yongnuo YN-622C II E-TTL?

Tags: yongnuo

I'm using a 5D Mark III and two Yongnuo YN-622C II E-TTL triggers. One is on the camera with 600EX II-RT speedlight on it and the other one is with another manual speedlight.

The problem is that I can't control manual settings of the flash that is on top of the camera. I have to go to the camera settings and change it there.  This is especially pain when I photograph moving objects.  Every change in power needs to be done on the camera settings not the flash itself.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking if the attached flash options can be changes on the flash unit itself? If so, you should say so. Make sure you reiterate any question you think you have asked in the title.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using TTL?

Comment: There are lots of reasons to want manual control over flash; I don't think that needs justification.

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is a design limitation of the 622 system.

Your solution is to not use the 600EX II on the camera. If you were to put a simple manual flash on the YN-622C II, on top of the camera, flash power can be adjusted on the flash itself.

Older Canon flash units like the 430EX, 550EX, and 580EX will also work this way because they were released before Canon had an in-camera flash menu.

There is an excellent guide for the Yongnuo 622 system available here:  [The Other YN-622C User Guide](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B77OmmGIg0gMMzZFaDVlZ1VNTE0/view)

[image]